# C pointers, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: c, pointers, runtime-error

i have no compilation errors, but it crashes on run-time,
that's my relevant code, first it's structs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Gas_Station *pgasStationHead = NULL;
typedef struct Gas_Station {
   char *name;
   double octan95SS;
 double octan95FS;
 double octan98SS;
 double octan98FS;
 double gasSoldTotal;
 double gasSoldSS;
 double gasSoldFS;
 struct Gas_Station *pgasStationNext;
 struct Client_List *pclientHead;
} Station;

typedef struct Client_List {
   char carID[10];
 char gasType[3];
   double gasAmount;
 char serviceType[12];
 struct Client_List *pclientNext;
} Client;
```

and after that the problematic area:

```
void CommandsSwitch(FILE *input , FILE *output) {

  do {
   int i;
   char *ptemp , *pfuncNum, *pcarID, *pstationName;
   ptemp = fgets(ptemp , 80 , input);
   if (ptemp[0] != '#') {
    pfuncNum = strtok(ptemp , ",");
    i = (int)pfuncNum[0];
    switch (i)
    {
     case 1:
     HowMuchGasPerStation(output);
     break;

     case 2 :
     pstationName = strtok(pstationName , ",");
     AverageGasInSpecieficStation(output , pstationName);
     break;

     case 3 :
     HowMuchGasInAllStations(output);
     break;

     case 4 :
     HowMuchGasFSInAllStations(output);
     break;

     case 5 :
     pcarID = strtok(ptemp , ",");
     HowMuchGasSoldByCarID(output , pcarID);
     break;
     case 6 :
     pcarID = strtok(ptemp , ",");
     pstationName = strtok(pstationName , ",");
     HowMuchGasSoldByStationPerCarID(output , pcarID , pstationName);
     break;
     case 7 :
     pcarID = strtok(ptemp , ",");
     StationsWithClientByCarID(output , pcarID);
     break;
     case 8 :
     pcarID = strtok(ptemp , ",");
     pstationName = strtok(pstationName , ",");
     HowMuchClientSpentByStation(output , pcarID , pstationName);
     break;
     case 9 :
     pcarID = strtok(ptemp , ",");
     HowMuchClientSpentInTotalByCarID(output , pcarID);
     break;

     case 10 :
     pstationName = strtok(pstationName , ",");
     ClientDetailsBySpecieficStation(output , pstationName);
     break;
    }
   }
  }while(!feof(input)); 

 fclose(input);
 fclose(output);
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
 int i;
 FILE *f , *input , *output;
 for (i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
  f = fopen(argv[i] , "r");
  if (f == NULL) {
   error("can't open file, might not exists");
  }
  else {
   AddStation(f);
   fclose(f);
  }

 }
 if (argv[1] != NULL) {
  input = fopen(argv[1] , "r");
  if (input == NULL) {
   error("can't open file, might not exists");
  }
 }

 output = fopen("result.txt" , "w");
 if (output == NULL) {
   error("can't open file");
 }
 CommandsSwitch(input , output);

return 0;
}`
```

in the CommandSwitch function the Call stack points to *ptemp, saying i can't use it because it didnt intialized or something...
what am i doing wrong?!

Comment: Please format your question, I cant understand a thing, and so, can't try to help you.

Comment: Could someone please edit the post?  Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need a debugger first - pinpoint *what* it is crashing at.

Comment: I already pointed out the error in answer to your previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187038/new-to-c-error-c2371-error-redefinition-diffrent-basic-types - you might want to try reading all the answers you get before moving on and asking the next question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `ptemp` variable is a pointer that is not initialized.
Use `malloc` to allocate appropriate space or define it as an array, instead.

Answer (score 4):

You have to allocate memory for `ptemp` prior to usage in `fgets`.

You can do it either dynamically or on the stack:

- `char ptemp[100];`
- `char* ptemp = (char*)malloc(100);`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one problem.

```
char *ptemp; 
ptemp = fgets(ptemp , 80 , input);
```

You told the compiler that `ptemp` is a pointer to some characters, but you never allocated space to store some characters to write into.  Maybe this should be:

```
char ptemp[80];
fgets(ptemp, sizeof(ptemp), input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing `char ptemp[80];` before the fgets() could help the error.  Or do `ptemp = (char *)malloc(80*sizeof(*ptemp));` before the fgets().

Answer (score 0):

Once you're done dealing with `ptemp` being an uninitialized pointer, you'll probably want to change this part as well:

```
pfuncNum = strtok(ptemp , ",");
i = (int)pfuncNum[0];
switch (i)
{
 case 1:
 // more cases up to `10` elided.
```

Right now, you're looking at the character value of the first character, so to get the `1`, the user would have to enter Ctrl+A, for `2` Ctrl+B, and so on. Getting the `10` would be particularly problematic, because that's a `line-feed` character.

My guess is that you want something like:

```
i = atoi(pfuncNum);
switch (i) { 
// ...
```

This will let the user actually enter the digit `1`, `2`, etc., in the command.
For real use, you probably want to replace `atoi` with something like `strtol` though (it improves the ability to deal well with bad input, among other things).

Once you've fixed that, you also want to take a second look at the basic structure of your loop. Almost any loop of the form:

```
do { 
    /* ... */ 
} while (!feof(input));
```

...pretty much guarantees that it won't work correctly (will typically process the last input twice). Since you're using `fgets` to read the string, you probably want to use something like this instead:

```
while (fgets(...)) {
    /* ... */ 
};
```